# how can I generate previous state of conway's game of life algorithm?

Tags: reverse

suppose we have ith state of conway's game of life algorithm how can I generate a previous state of this algorithm

I have no idea about this problem

Answer (score 3):

> Conway's Game of Life, one of the most famous cellular automaton rules, is not reversible: for instance, it has many patterns that die out completely, so the configuration in which all cells are dead has many predecessors, and it also has Garden of Eden patterns with no predecessors. However, another rule called "Critters" by its inventors, Tommaso Toffoli and Norman Margolus, is reversible and has similar dynamic behavior to Life.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_cellular_automaton

Comment: I would assume you could come up with one previous generation, beyond which you would lose data.

Comment: That just means that you are not guaranteed to be able to generate a predecessor state, not that there is no way to calculate predecessors. "The set of predecessors has size zero" is a valid result.